# How would I concatenate a string based on if a var has a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to concatenate a web address based on if my inputs have a value, for instance I want to get just two values out of the four vars. either the awayVal or homeVal and either the awayId or homeId. If the input has a value, I want to grab that value along with that inputs id and not the other.

I then want to concatenate it into something that looks like this:

https://--------.islandshore.net/dbdata/bet/new/1/"+ gameId +"/"+ id +"/"+ value

What would be a good way of doing this? Sorry if that was a tad confusing, please let me clarify if you're not understanding what I'm trying to do.

```
$('.wrapper').append('\
<div id="' + gameId + '" class="main-wrapper col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">\
    <div class="game-cards">\
        <div class="chart-container">\
            <canvas id="' + homeTeam + '" width="500" height="500"></canvas>\
        </div>\
        <div class="right-info">\
            <h4>' + awayTeam + '<br>' + " @ " + '<br>' + homeTeam + '</h4>\
            <h5 id="time-channel">' + gameDate + ' @ ' + gameTime + '<br>' + ' On ' + network + '</h5>\
            <div class="total-points-live">\
                <h5>Total Points Bet</h5>\
                <h5 id="point-total">' + pointTotal + '</h5>\
                <p>' + awayTeam + '</p>\
                <input class="bet-input-away" data-away-id="' + awayId + '" data-team-type="' + awayTeam + '" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="betAmountAway" placeholder="Wager Amount">\
                <p>' + homeTeam + '</p>\
                <input class="bet-input-home" data-home-id="' + homeId + '" data-team-type="' + homeTeam + '" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="betAmountHome" placeholder="Wager Amount">\
                <p class="bet-button" gameid="' + gameId + '">Click To Place Bet</p>\
            </div>\
        </div>\
    </div>\ ');

 $('.wrapper').on('click', '.bet-button', function() {
             var self = $(this);
             var gameId = self.attr('gameid');
             var awayVal = $('#' + gameId + ' input[name=betAmountAway]').val();
             var homeVal = $('#' + gameId + ' input[name=betAmountHome]').val();
             var awayId = $('#' + gameId + ' .bet-input-away').data('away-id');
             var homeId = $('#' + gameId + ' .bet-input-home').data('home-id'); // This is what sends the bet to the server. $.ajax({ url: "https://-------.islandshore.net/dbdata/bet/new/1/" + gameId + "/" + awayId + "/" + homeVal || awayVal + "", type: "get", success: function(response) { $('#' + gameId + ' input[name=betAmountHome]').val(''); //This resets the value box $('#' + gameId + ' input[name=betAmountAway]').val(''); //This resets the value box console.log("https://--------.islandshore.net/dbdata/bet/new/1/" + gameId + "/" + awayId + "/" + homeVal || awayVal + "") }, error: function(xhr) { console.log('xhr') } }); console.log(awayId); console.log(homeId); console.log(gameId); console.log(homeVal); console.log(awayVal); }); });
```

Comment: Are you asking how to concatenate or how to check if a variable has a value? Because it kinda sounds like all you want it to know how to check if a variable has a value, and for that you can just use e.g. var !== null, var !== 'undefined', if(var), if(var !== '').

Comment: I'm trying to see if the var has a value, if it does I want that value, but I also want that that inputs id, I need two separate vars for them in order to concatenate the URL correctly.

Comment: Sounds like you need a set of radios to make the decision for you on what values to use. Or Radios and only 2 inputs even

Comment: @charlietfl there should be a way to do this without radios hopefully.

Comment: Having an absolute indicator of which combination to use is best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned only one value is possible you can do this:

```
var id, value;

// If the awayVal is set, assign away info to id and value variables
if (awayVal) {
  id = awayId;
  value = awayVal;
}
// If the homeVal is set, assign home info to id and value variables
if (homeVal) {
  id = homeId;
  value = homeVal;
}

// If there is the possibility that none of the values (awayVal or homeVal) is set and the user can execute you need to check if they are valid
if (!value) {
    // handle error
}

// Build your url with id and value variable
var url = `http://yoururl.com/${gameId}/${id}/${value}`;
```

Additionally you might want to check/validate if at least one of the values is set before sending that ajax call

Comment: Can you explain this more? I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: I'm confused as to how you are setting the vars id and value with var id, value;

Comment: I just create them and don't assign a value yet. They are undefined until they are set in those if conditions

Comment: Ok this works, gameid was throwing an error because I wasn't capitalized and it was screwing with me haha, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
var id = awayId || homeId;
var value = awayVal || homeVal;

var url = `https://--------.islandshore.net/dbdata/bet/new/1/${gameid}/${id}/${value}`
```

Plus you could use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to avoid using all those `+`

Comment: What would determine the or though?

Comment: @BrettKessler var id = awayId || homeId; means that if awayId has a value id will be set to awayId, if it doesn't it'll instead be set to homeId

Comment: @BrettKessler You can read more about this here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: So that would work for the var value but since hey id exists for both I don't know that it would work for the id, any suggestions?

Comment: @BrettKessler Depending which one you want to have more priority. If both have a value It will take the first one from left to right

Comment: Well they both have an ID value, I'm wanting the id from the input that has a value.

Comment: But you only send one ajax call, so if both have a value you have to prioritize one or you need to check the values first and send 2 ajax calls

Comment: Well the way that this has to function is that I only want the one with a value to go through, I set it so the other input can't be submitted so there will only be one input value at a time.